# I am facing issue on data binding with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new to Angular JS. I am facing issue on data binding with AngularJS. It works for string but it does not work for datetime. I am using ASP.net MVC with Angular JS and jQuery UI for Date Picker.

1. Data comes from database(controller) in JSON format.
2. Through data binding using Angular JS it automatically set to input boxes.
3. In input box jQuery UI Date picker is attached.

It works for all the fields except datetime.

Case 1: If I set input type="date" 
    then input date field is empty.

Case 2: If I set input type="string"
    then it shows value in input ie. /Date(1481481000000)/

### Here is my controller code:

```
    // GET: ProductMaster/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int PrimaryKey)
    {
        try
        {
            using (LOAN_APPRAISAL_TESTEntities db = new LOAN_APPRAISAL_TESTEntities())
            {

                var v = (from v1 in db.m_ProductMaster where v1.ProductID == PrimaryKey select v1).First();
                ProductMasterModel product = new ProductMasterModel();
                v.MapToModelObject(product);
                return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            return Json(new ResultModel() { Result = tssiplResultType.tssiplError, Message = e1.Message, Data = null }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

### Here is my Angular JS Code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/ProductMaster/Details',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: { PrimaryKey: ProductID },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            HideBusy();
            alert(a.responseText);
        },
        success: function (a, b, c) {
            HideBusy();
            debugger;
            $scope.ProductMasterModel = a; // this is my Angular Model

            //debugger;
              //debugger;
            $('#divEdit').modal('show');
        }
    });
```

### Here is my HTML

```
                        <div class='input-group date .form_datetime'>
                            <label>Valid From</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ControlType="Date" type="date" 
                                   min="1900-01-01"
                                   max="2500-01-01"
                                   ng-model="ProductMasterModel.ValidFrom" />

                        </div>


                        <label>Valid To</label>
                        <input class="form-control" ControlType="Date" type="text" 
                                   min="1900-01-01"
                                   max="2500-01-01"
                                   ng-model="ProductMasterModel.ValidTo"/>
```

> Note:
>   I don't want to use input type="date" as HTML5 date picker does not works on all browser, hence prefer to use jQuery UI datepicker.

I have gone through several links, every one is showing formatting date and display it in span.

Comment: It would appreciable if you elaborate your comment

Comment: Your server side Datetime format needs to be parsed to a format useable by javascript `Date()`. This can easily be searched on the web and there are multiple ways to do it

Comment: Well, this is Angular JS code see ng-model. What I have understood is data binding works on JSON and it should bind with html. Now my json data comes from my ajax call... secondly it works for string and integer values but it does not works date time. I also understand that data binding happens internally, How can I do this?

Comment: Also never ever ever use `async: false,` . It is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browsers and you must be ignoring their deprecation warnings in your console

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for Ajax call instead of Angular's '$http' function?

Comment: Ok. Got it, I will remove this and use $http, but the question is still remains. Once it is through, Such thing will be taken care of in refactoring

Answer (score 0):

Use angular `$filter` in your field

```
 <input class="form-control" ControlType="Date" type="text" min="1900-01-01"
                                   max="2500-01-01"
                                   ng-model="ProductMasterModel.ValidFrom | date" />
```

Comment: So what is your opinion oon type="date", it should be type="text" or  type="date"

Comment: **Your wish**.  custom filter can return any data type which you want to use

Comment: No, formatting is not working with type="date" nor type="text"

Comment: Just go through with custom filter. if you want type=text, then make the filter is return string value else datetime value

Comment: After assign standard date filter in ng-model, it gives me error "Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngModel/nonassign?p0=ProductMasterModel.ValidFrom". Can you please let me know where I am wrong